# Boolean Intersect not working - Blender Guru's Abandoned House Tutorial

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

[image]

first time posting, just a bit stuck, probably through fault of my own and not understanding blender well enough.

I started Blender Guru's "How to make an abandoned house in Blender - Tutorial" and I've tried following it before, and I get stuck at the same spot each time.

Basically, in the tutorial, a couple minutes in, he makes "clap board siding". He duplicates the base edges of the house, seperates it, extrudes it upwards a tiny bit and then scales the bottom out to make the siding. He then uses Array, copying the siding panel all the way up the house base, and onto the roof wall triangle, at which point the siding jutts out past the shape of the triangle. He then uses Solidify on the pannels, and finally a boolean to cut the siding into the shape of the wall of the roof. (boolean > intersect > fast > object selected is the base house).

Sometimes this process has worked, other times it has gone wrong, but the final step is to scale the frame of the house slightly larger than the siding, and then turn the house frame in viewport display to wire in object properties. Every time I try and resize and wireframe the base house, it hides the siding on the roof walls no matter what I do.

I've closed blender and remade it on a new file three times, and tried different house shapes and all of them end up with invisible siding when it came to the triangle of the roof wall. I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not educated in blender well enough to know what.

[image: the siding, after using array, before using boolean]

[image: boolean added, sometimes already the roof wall disappears, luckily not this time]

[image: resized the house frame slightly larger and changed it to wire, no more siding on the roof wall ????]

Comment: pls add at least a link to the tutorial with time (where the issue happened) so we can see at least what he did. And if you really wanna help us (to help you), you should include your blend file so we also see/know what you did.

Comment: https://youtu.be/1aNnERnHRZg?t=88 this is the video im referencing

Comment: i dont know how to add my blender file im sorry

Comment: just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions ;)

Comment: done :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your base house mesh has its roof open at the top, meaning it's not a manifold (watertight) geometry so the boolean modifier doesn't know what to do with that part. Blender Guru doesn't warn against this in his video so this is a very common question. You need to close your roof.

- Go into Edit Mode and switch to *Vertices* mode (use the left-most button at the top left corner of the screen, or press <kbd>1</kbd> when in *Edit Mode*).
- Select the top two vertices of your roof and press <kbd>F</kbd> (stands for *Fill*) to create a line between them.
- While that new middle edge is still selected, press <kbd>F</kbd> again. This will create a new face on one side of that edge
- Select the top two vertices one more and press <kbd>F</kbd> again to create a face on the other side. Boolean modifier should now work:

[image]

I'm using the *Local View* option—<kbd>Numpad /</kbd>—to isolate the view to the selected/active object.

Another thing to note is that while this fixes the boolean operation, the mesh is not actually fully manifold yet, since the two edges we created on the two sides (gutter level) are not connected to the vertices in between. Ideally you would create new edge loops to bind them, but that's another lesson:

[image]

Comment: You are my hero!! Thank you very much for the help.